# The order of the cyclic subgroups of $GL(3,q)$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Derek Holt gave an counter example of my question 
because i had forgotten to write this fact that $p,q$ are distinct primes. Thus i repair my question.

Let $G=P \ltimes Q$ be a finite group scuch that $P$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$ which $P$ is non-normal cyclic and $P=C_G(P)=N_G(P)$ and $G'=Q \cong C_q \times C_q \times C_q$, where $p,q$ are distinct primes.
. Also assume that $G$ has the properties that if $H,K$ be two distinct non-normal non-cyclic subgroup of $G$, then $H,K$ are conjugate in $G$.

We see that there exists a homomorphism $\varphi : P \longrightarrow Aut(Q)\cong GL(3,q)$. also clearly, $Ker(\varphi)=C_P(Q)=Z(G)$.
I want to know why $P \cong C_p$, where $p=q^2+q+1$ is a prime.

Comment: What leads you to believe that this statement is true?

Comment: I am still not clear what $p$ is. I understand that you want to assume that $p$ is prime, but what is $p$ exactly? Are you defining $p = q^2+q+1$?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a counterexample with $q=11$. The group ${\rm GL}(3,11)$ has a unique conjugacy class of cyclic subgroups of order $133 = 7 \times 19$.

Let $Q$ be elementary abelian of order $11^3$, let $P \cong C_p$ with $p=133$, and let $G = P \ltimes Q$ with the action corresponding to this cyclic subgroup of ${\rm GL}(3,q)$. The action of $P$ on $Q$ is irreducible, so $P$ is maximal in $G$ and hence $P=C_G(P)=N_G(P)$. Clearly $G'=Q$.

So we have to check the condition that all non-normal non-cyclic subgroups are conjugate in $G$. Let $H$ be a non-cyclic subgroup of $G$. Since $G/Q$ is cyclic, $H \cap Q \ne 1$.

But all nontrivial subgroups of $P$ (i.e. $P$ itself and its subgroups of orders $7$ and $19$) act irreducibly on $Q$, so either $Q \le H$ or $H \le Q$, If $Q \le H$ then $H \unlhd G$, so we can assume that $H < Q$. Then $H$ non-cyclic implies that $|H|=q^2$.

Now $Q$ has exactly $q^2+q+1=133$ subgroups of order $q^2$. Since $P$ and its nontrivial subgroups act irreducibly on $Q$, they cannot normalize $H$, so these $133$ subgroups are all conjugate under the action of $P$.

Note that the fact that $Q$ has $q^2+q+1$ subgroups of order $q^2$, which must all be conjugate under the action of $P$, means that $|P|$ must be divisible by $q^2+q+1$.

If $|P| > q^2+q+1$ then by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, some nontrivial element $g$ of $P$ must stabilize (i.e. normalize) some subgroup $R$ of order $q^2$. Now $\langle g,R \rangle$ is a non-normal subgroup of $G$ of order greater than $q^2$, so it cannot be conjugate to the subgroups of order $q^2$, contradicting the hypotheses. So $|P|=q^2+q+1$.

Comment: The fact that $133$ is not a prime means that it is a counterexample. You asked for help in proving that $P \cong C_p$ where $p=q^2+q+1$ is prime. I have produced an example where it is not prime, so what you are trying to prove is false. You may be angry with me, but in fact I have a lot of time (probably nearly an hour) trying to help you.

Comment: @Rima don't yell. It's an inappropriate behaviour.

Comment: Now you have edited the question. If you change a question after it has been answered, then of course the answer may no longer be correct.  You have not said what $p$ is. Is $|P|=p$?

Comment: I am apologize. you right. I I've edited my question and put in site again. I'm sorry and thanks for response

Comment: Dear Derek Holt, Forgive me for my  inappropriate behavior?

Comment: Yes forgiven! I will try and answer the question when you have said what $p$ is.

Comment: Thanks, $p,q$ are distinct  primes

Comment: Dear Derek Holt, my professor gave a hint but i dont understand! Do you understand his hint? (Hint: the generator of $P$ permutes all subgroups of $Q$). Ofcourse, i see  that $Q$ has $q^2 +q +1$ elements of order $q$ but dont understand $\vert P \vert=p^n=q^2 +q +1$. How can we say $\vert P \vert=p^n=q^2 +q +1$?

Comment: I have added an extra paragraph to my answer showing how to prove that $|P|=q^2+q+1$.

Comment: thanks a lot, can we say $\vert P \vert=q^2 +q+1$ by orbit-stabilizer theorem when $P$ acts on the set of all elemnets of order $q$ of $Q$?

Comment: I think you want to take the subgroups of order $q$ rather than the elements. There are exactly $q^2+q+q$ subgroups of order $q$, so if $|P|>q^2+q+1$ then some element of $P$ stabilizes a subgroup and you get a non-normal non-cyclic subgroup.

Comment: are you sure? in  my book, if $G \cong C_q \times C_q \times C_q$, then $G$ has $q^2+q+1$ elements of order $q$. is ok?

Comment: Every element of $G$ except the identity has order $q$, so there are $q^3-1=(q^2+q+1)(q-1)$ elements of order $q$.

Comment: i think your reason is false, because $C_q \times C_q$ has exactly $q+1$ distinct elements of order $q$ but your reason says that this number is equal to $q^2 -1$!

Comment: because you dont consider case that two subgroups are equal

Comment: You are confused. $C_q \times C_q$ has $q^2-1$ elements of order $q$ and $q+1$ subgroups of order $q$.

Comment: The subgroup Of order $q$ is equal to cyclic group generated by an elemet of order $q$, I dont understand your means!

Comment: Yes that's right. It also has $q^2+q+1$ subgroups of order $q^2$. These all have to be conjugate under the action of $P$.

Comment: Can you explain me why $Q$ has $q^2+q+1$ subgroup of order $q^2$, please?

Comment: Choose two linearly independent generators and divide by the number of pairs of linearly independent generators that generate a specific subgroup to give $(q^3-1)(q^3-q)/((q^2-1)(q^2-q))= q^2+q+1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i am so confused in the counting of subgroups, any way trust you instead my book! because my book exercise say that the number of subgroups of order $q$ is equal to $q^2+q+1$

Comment: Your book is correct, there are $q^2+q+1$ subgroups of order $q$.

Comment: but you say that this number is equal to $q^2+q+q$!

Comment: If $X= \lbrace x \in Q \mid |x|=q \rbrace$, then $P$ acts on $X$ by conjugation, this action is transitive?

Comment: Im so sorry, this is last question. in your answer, why $r |q^2-1$ and why an element of order r in $GL(3,q)$ fixes does not act irreducibly, so an element of order $r$ in $P$ would normalize a subgroup of $Q$ of order $q$ or $q2$

Comment: Sorry, $q^2+q+q$ was a typo. I meant $q^2+q+1$.

Comment: I have replaced the proof that $|P|$ cannot be greater than $q^2+q+1$ by a simpler argument based on the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much, i learned a lot from you, thanks a lot